# MATLAB ind2sub equivalent in Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Matlab has two functions for converting matrix subscripts to linear indices and vice versa. (ind2sub and sub2ind)

I found the equivalent for R but is there an equivalent way in Python?

Comment: Check here: https://github.com/jjakeman/pyheat/blob/master/utilities/math_utils.py

Comment: I think you'll have better luck if you tell us what you're trying to do.  "I'm trying to replicate this function from another language" isn't often very helpful.  A better question would be formatted something like <description of the function you are trying to write (with sample inputs and outputs)> -- <some code you've tried> -- <(optional) errors your code is throwing) and description about what isn't working> -- <statement that this is reproducing function X from language Y for those familiar with language Y>

Comment: You could look into numpy's [`unravel_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html).

Comment: @eigenchris - Nice find.  I didn't know what to search for so I just wrote something myself lol.

Comment: @rayryeng Since joining SO I've had a number of "oh, there's a function for that" experiences. Before I'd be coding the equivalent of `bsxfun` or `accumarray` because I didn't know any better.

Comment: @eigenchris - Me too lol.  One time I was trying to compute the discrete derivative, when Amro or someone just used `diff`. *face palm*.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A Google search lead me to this link: https://github.com/jjakeman/pyheat/blob/master/utilities/math_utils.py

<s>From what I can tell, there is no direct implementation of those functions in MATLAB</s>.

---

Just turns out I can't read the documentation properly.  If you want the functionality of `sub2ind`, you'll want the [`ravel_multi_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html#numpy.ravel_multi_index) function.  The function declaration says that you require two inputs.  The first input is a 2D `numpy` array where each row are the locations for a particular dimension.  For example, if you wanted to apply `ind2sub` on a 2D matrix, you would specify a 2D `numpy` array where the first row consists of all of the row locations you want, and the second row consists of all of the column locations you want.  The second input is tuple that determines the size of each dimension, so for a 2D array, it'd be the number of rows and columns.

To do `ind2sub`, you'd want the [`unravel_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) function.  The first input is an array of linear indices that you want converted into locations of each dimension in your array.  The second input is a tuple of dimensions like previously.

I'm going to leave the post at the bottom for posterity, in case you want to try and implement these yourself.

---

However, you can certainly implement those yourself.  I'm assuming that because you tagged your post with `numpy` that you'll want a `numpy`-esque solution.  Remember, in `numpy` you access elements in **row** major, not **column** major, and so given two arrays such that one is for row and the other for column indices (0-indexed), `sub2ind` for 2D matrices is very simply:

```
def sub2ind(array_shape, rows, cols):
    return rows*array_shape[1] + cols
```

`array_shape` is an array of two elements where the first element is the number of rows in the matrix and the second element is the number of columns.  If you recall, you can access an element in a row-major matrix by:

```
ind = r*cols + c
```

`(r,c)` are the row and column index you want, provided it's 0-indexed.  To go the opposite way, you would use integer division and the modulus:

```
def ind2sub(array_shape, ind):
    rows = (ind.astype('int') / array_shape[1])
    cols = (ind.astype('int') % array_shape[1]) # or numpy.mod(ind.astype('int'), array_shape[1])
    return (rows, cols)
```

Here, the output is a two-element tuple where the first element is the row locations and the second element is the column locations.  To summarize `ind2sub`, to access the row you want, you take the linear index and do an integer division with the columns.  To get the column you want, you find the modulus or the remainder.  Going to 3 dimensions and onwards is a bit more complicated.  I'll leave you to take a look at the link I referred above for more details.

Obviously, I didn't place any error checking in the above functions, so you'd obviously use `array_shape` to your advantage in that case.  A better way of doing what you want would be something like:

```
def sub2ind(array_shape, rows, cols):
    ind = rows*array_shape[1] + cols
    ind[ind < 0] = -1
    ind[ind >= array_shape[0]*array_shape[1]] = -1
    return ind

def ind2sub(array_shape, ind):
    ind[ind < 0] = -1
    ind[ind >= array_shape[0]*array_shape[1]] = -1
    rows = (ind.astype('int') / array_shape[1])
    cols = ind % array_shape[1]
    return (rows, cols)
```

I did some basic error checking to ensure that no rows or columns for `sub2ind` or linear indices for `ind2sub` are out of bounds.  I set those locations to -1 so you know you messed up somewhere.

Good luck!

Comment: I wish the official documentation was also written in this way.

Comment: @rayryeng hello! It is very strange that no one knows how to solve my problem in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66165387/error-not-aligned-matrix-multiplication-in-python?noredirect=1#comment116982344_66165387 ? Can you please help me? thank you a lot

Answer (score 14):

I think you want [ravel_multi_index](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html#numpy.ravel_multi_index) and [unravel_index](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html#numpy.unravel_index)

Answer (score 6):

Building on @rayryeng and @theblackcat's answers, you should also note that you will have to use Fortran style indexing, and recall that Python is 0 indexed whilst MATLAB is 1 indexed.

The Fortran style requirement tricked me up for a bit.

In Python:

```
np.unravel_index(7, [1, 2, 3, 4], 'F')
(0, 1, 0, 1)
```

and in MATLAB/Octave

```
[a, b, c, d] = ind2sub([1, 2, 3, 4], 8)
a =  1
b =  2
c =  1
d =  2
```

Answer (score 1):

For 2D matrices, you can use Python's built-in `divmod` function (returns the quotient and remainder of division). To get subscripts `(r,c)` of a `nrows x ncols` matrix, use:

`(r, c) = divmod(ind, ncols)` for row-major ordering

`(c, r) = divmod(ind, nrows)` for column-major ordering

---

For example, a 3x6 matrix in row-major (C style) ordering:

```
  0     1     2     3     4     5
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)

  6     7     8     9    10    11
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5)

 12    13    14    15    16    17
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4) (2,5)
```

```
(0, 0) = divmod(0, 6)
(0, 3) = divmod(3, 6)
(1, 0) = divmod(6, 6)
(1, 5) = divmod(11, 6)
(2, 2) = divmod(14, 6)
```

---

A 3x6 matrix in column-major (Fortran style) ordering:

```
  0     3     6     9    12    15
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)

  1     4     7    10    13    16
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5)

  2     5     8    11    14    17
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4) (2,5)
```

```
(0, 0) = divmod(0, 3)        #r=0, c=0
(1, 0) = divmod(3, 3)        #r=0, c=1
(2, 0) = divmod(6, 3)        #r=0, c=2
(3, 2) = divmod(11, 3)       #r=2, c=3
(4, 2) = divmod(14, 3)       #r=2, c=4
```