# multi indexing in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I am trying to index a large array, so that penultimately I can have a 4-d array with values to each of the points , I can do this in matlab using sub2ind, but I can't figure out how to do it in python, any help would be appreciated (I am also not sure if my indexing is right (I know matlab goes from 1, python goes from 0)

```
#Create the array
[Nx, Ny, Nz] = (60, 220, 85)
[I, J, K]    = (np.arange(1,Nx+1,1),np.arange(1,Ny+1,1),np.arange(1,Nz+1,1))
[I, J, K] = np.meshgrid(I, J, K)

print([I])
ix=np.ravel_multi_index((Nx,Ny,Nz), (I[:], J[:], K[:]), order='F')
```

Thanks in advance

This is a 3d array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MATLAB ind2sub equivalent in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995146/matlab-ind2sub-equivalent-in-python) (and vice versa).

Comment: Sorry this is for a 3d array

Comment: You are right, it has similar content but does not adress directly the 3D case

Comment: Can you help me with this please? :(

Comment: It'd be a pleasure, but I do not know the answer :z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working, think it was because of the indexing and didn't structure the arguments correctly

```
#Create the array
[Nx, Ny, Nz] = (60, 220, 85)
[I, J, K]    = (np.arange(0,Nx,1),np.arange(0,Ny,1),np.arange(0,Nz,1))

[I, J, K] = np.meshgrid(I, J, K)

#Create the 1-d idexed array
ix = np.ravel_multi_index((I,J,K),(Nx,Ny,Nz),order='F')

print(ix)
```

Comment: I see you were on the right track with the index convention difference