# MATLAB ind2sub and Numpy unravel_index inconsistency

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Based on the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33072609):

Using Octave, I get:

```
>> [x, y, z] = ind2sub([27, 5, 58], 3766)
x =  13
y =  5
z =  28
```

Using Numpy, I get:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.unravel_index(3765, (27, 5, 58))
(12, 4, 53)
```

Why, in Numpy, the `z` component is 58, when it should be 27 according to octave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab folows column-major (Fortran-style) ordering, while NumPy follows row-major (C-style) ordering.

The NumPy function `unravel_index(indices, dims, order='C')` has an optional parameter `order` which determines whether the indices should be viewed as indexing in row-major (C-style) or column-major (Fortran-style) order. It defaults to `order='C'`.

```
[x, y ,z] = np.unravel_index(3765, (27, 5, 58))                 # x=12, y=4, z=53
[x, y ,z] = np.unravel_index(3765, (27, 5, 58), order='F')      # x=12, y=4, z=27
```

Answer (score 3):

Well with MATLAB that follows column-major indexing, for `(x,y,z)` the elements are stored at `x`, then `y` and then `z`. With NumPy for `(x,y,z)` because of row-major indexing, it's the other way - `z`, `y` and then `x`. So, to replicate the same behavior in NumPy, you need to flip the grid shape for use with `np.unravel_index` and finally flip the output indices, like so -

```
np.unravel_index(3765, (58, 5, 27))[::-1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [18]: np.unravel_index(3765, (58, 5, 27))[::-1]
Out[18]: (12, 4, 27)
```

Comment: So simple. Thanks!