# Error: not aligned matrix multiplication in Python

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication, cvxpy

I want to perform the following least squares minimization problem in python using `cvxpy`:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

# Generate the data
m = 20
n = 15
A = np.random.randn(m, n+2)
b = np.random.randn(m)

# Define and solve the CVXPY problem.
x1 = cp.Variable(1) # a single variable
x2 = cp.Variable(1) # a single variable
x3 = cp.Variable(n) # a vector of length n

cost_func = cp.sum_squares(A .dot([x1, x2, x3]) - b)
problem = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cost_func))
problem.solve()
```

I am always getting the error "**shapes (20,17) and (3,) not aligned: 17 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)**". This means that `cvx` doesn't consider `[x1, x2, x3]` as a `n+2-vector` but a `3-vector`.

I tried to replace `.dot` by `@` but also didn't work. How can I do the matrix multiplication inside the sum_squares above?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: To join variables use vstack, hstack or something of this kind.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thank you. I tried it and doesn't work. If you have any intuition please provide me a detailed answer about how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comment:

```
cost_func = cp.sum_squares(A .dot([x1, x2, x3]) - b)
->
cost_func = cp.sum_squares(A @ cp.hstack([x1, x2, x3]) - b)
```

See [Docs: Vector/matrix functions](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/functions/index.html#vector-matrix-functions)